# ReSharper not identifying XAML Resources as Localizable

Tags: wpf, localization, resharper

I have a WPF project and am trying to use R# to localize.  It is working great with one caveat.  It identifies all the localizable strings in my primary code but it's not identifying them in XAML files.  I can go through the files manually and Ctrl-RO and it will move them to the resource file just fine but it doesn't identify them for me.

It's been a while since I did localization but I really thought it used to do this, what am I missing?  I looked through the settings but everything I could see was turned on.  The project is set to localizable and the inspector is set to pessimistic.

I feel like I'm missing something dumb but I don't know what it is.  If anyone can point me to it I would be very grateful...

Comment: This also means that when I have resources that are already there I can't Alt-Enter and tell it to use that resource, I have to manually go find the resource and then manually replace the text field with the resource designation.  Not a huge deal but if you have many it's less fun...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAML files are not supported by the ReSharper localization mechanism, there is a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-336719) about this matter.

Comment: Bummer, I swore it did that before but I must be mistaken.  Thanks for the answer, just voted on the feature request.